# How to check if a variable is larger than multiple other variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check if a variable is greater than 4 other variables. 
Is there a way to do this?
so far i've tried

```
if(Guitar > Percussion || Brass || Keyboard || Woodwind)
            {
            var guitarpage = document.getElementById("GuitarPage");
            guitarpage.style.display ="block";
            }

        if(Percussion > Guitar || Brass || Keyboard || Woodwind) 
            {
            var percussionpage = document.getElementById("PercussionPage");
            percussionpage.style.display ="block";

            }

        if(Brass > Percussion || Guitar || Keyboard || Woodwind) {
            var brasspage = document.getElementById("BrassPage");
            brasspage.style.display ="block";
            }

        if(Keyboard > Percussion || Guitar || Brass || Woodwind) {
            var keyboardpage = document.getElementById("KeyboardPage");
            keyboardpage.style.display ="block";
            }

        if(Woodwind > Percussion || Guitar || Keyboard || Brass) {
            var woodpage = document.getElementById("WoodwindPage");
            woodpage.style.display ="block";
    }
```

as well as using && but I either get every div being displayed or none at all.

Comment: `(Guitar > Percussion || Brass || Keyboard || Woodwind)` ==> `(Guitar > Percussion || Guitar > Brass || Guitar > Keyboard || Guitar > Woodwind)`

Comment: What are the values given to the items?Are they numbers?

Comment: use math.max( [arr of variables] ) with one condition

Comment: use switch case instead of if else ladder

Answer (score 2):

```
Guitar > Percussion || Brass || Keyboard || Woodwind
```

evaluates as

```
(Guitar > Percussion) || Brass || Keyboard || Woodwind
```

which will be true if `Guitar > Percussion`, or the first falsy value among `Brass`, `Keyboard` and `Percussion`.

What you want is `(Guitar > Percussion && Guitar > Brass && Guitar > Keyboard && Guitar > Woodwind)`. Even better, you can do this:

```
var vals = [Guitar, Percussion, Brass, Keyboard, Woodwind];
var pageNames = ["GuitarPage", "PercussionPage", "BrassPage", "KeyboardPage", "WoodwindPage"];
var max = Math.max.apply(null, vals);
var index = vals.indexOf(max);
if (vals.indexOf(max, index + 1) == -1) {
  var pageName = pageNames[index];
  var page = document.getElementById(pageName);
  page.style.display = "block";
}
```

EDIT: The `if` checks if there is a second value that is also `max`, and avoids doing the operation in that case; this makes it equivalent to OP's code.

Comment: What does switch do?

Comment: @user3500310 [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: `switch` checks a single value against multiple constants. But I changed it to a better approach.

Comment: Afaict, this checks `>=` instead of `>` and picks the first of the possibly equal greatest, but I agree, this is probably what the op means to do.

Comment: @Amadan Suggestion: We can now use spread operator. `Math.max(...values)` instead of `apply`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: You are right, it will find the first value that is max.

Comment: @Tushar: [Not on IE](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator)

Comment: This is doing my head in xD. So Math.max.apply(null,values) Is doing what exactly?

Comment: `Math.max(2,8,4)` is finding the largest element (here, `8`). `.apply(receiver, arglist)` on a function will call that function as a method on the `receiver` object (or without one if `null`), with the `arglist` as arguments; so `Math.max.apply(null, [2, 8, 4])` is almost the same as `Math.max(2, 8, 4)`. "almost" because the receiver is different; to make it same, you would have to say `Math.max.apply(Math, [2, 8, 4])`. As Tushar says, in new JS (ES6), we got the spread operator that does the same thing a bit more prettily: `Math.max(...[2, 8, 4])`. In short, it will find the biggest value.

Answer (score 1):

For checking if a variable is greater than all other variable you need to use `&&` instead of `||` as given below:

```
if (Percussion > Guitar && 
   Percussion > Brass && 
   Percussion > Keyboard && Percussion > Woodwind)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you must do it the long way, like so, for each of the variables:

`if (Percussion > Guitar && Percussion > Brass && Percussion > Keyboard && Percussion > Woodwind)`

This would check if the `Percussion` variable is greater than all of the other variables. Also, to check if the `Percussion` is greater than **all** of the other variables you must use  `&&` instead of `||`, like in the example.

Good luck!

Comment: why is woodwind by itself and not woodwind&&percussion?

Comment: Sorry, I think the line broke in an awkward position, this is the code: `if (Percussion > Guitar && Percussion > Brass && Percussion > Keyboard && Percussion > Woodwind)`

Comment: Oh no its not that I'm just thinking should it be if (Percussion > Guitar && Percussion > Brass && Percussion > Keyboard && Percussion > Woodwind && Percussion) ?

Comment: No, that is not right because at the end there, you are evaluating the expression `Percussion` by itself as a boolean, which would cause an error because I think in the context of your problem the variable `Percussion` is not a boolean, so it cannot evaluate to a true/false expression by itself.

Comment: So I repeated it for each instrument ( 5 times) Is there a way for it not to check every single "if" statement if one of them is true?

Comment: yes, you can use an `else if` statement. This can be added to the end of an if statement, like so: `if (3>5) {/* Will not be executed*/} else if (2<4) {/* Will be executed */} else if (10<100) {/*Will not be executed*/}`