# How to stop and if statement if another if statement is true

Tags: javascript

Just a quick one How do I change this code so that when one of the if statements become true it just skips the rest?

```
    if (Guitar > Percussion && Guitar > Brass && Guitar > Keyboard && Guitar > Woodwind) // Here I'm checking to see if Guitar is greater than the others
            {
            var guitarpage = document.getElementById("GuitarPage"); // If guitar is then get the Element ID "GuitarPage"
            guitarpage.style.display ="block"; // Then Display that page
            }

        if (Percussion > Guitar && Percussion > Brass && Percussion > Keyboard && Percussion > Woodwind)
            {
            var percussionpage = document.getElementById("PercussionPage");
            percussionpage.style.display ="block";

            }

        if (Brass > Guitar && Brass > Brass && Percussion > Keyboard && Brass > Woodwind) {
            var brasspage = document.getElementById("BrassPage");
            brasspage.style.display ="block";
            }

        if (Keyboard > Guitar && Keyboard > Keyboard && Percussion > Brass && Keyboard > Woodwind) {
            var keyboardpage = document.getElementById("KeyboardPage");
            keyboardpage.style.display ="block";
            }

        if (Woodwind > Guitar && Woodwind > Brass && Woodwind > Keyboard && Woodwind > Percussion) {
            var woodpage = document.getElementById("WoodwindPage");
            woodpage.style.display ="block";
                        }

        else {
            var nonepage = document.getElementById ("NoPage");
            nonepage.style.display ="block";

            }
```

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Use `else if` or `switch`. Amandan has [beautiful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36539726/2025923), why not use that?

Comment: I still can't figure that out sorry! 
But thanks for that!

Comment: Just realised doesn't else if continue down the if statements if its true?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Guitar > Percussion && Guitar > Brass && Guitar > Keyboard && Guitar > Woodwind) // Here I'm checking to see if Guitar is greater than the others
            {
            var guitarpage = document.getElementById("GuitarPage"); // If guitar is then get the Element ID "GuitarPage"
            guitarpage.style.display ="block"; // Then Display that page
            }

else if (Percussion > Guitar && Percussion > Brass && Percussion > Keyboard && Percussion > Woodwind)
            {
            var percussionpage = document.getElementById("PercussionPage");
            percussionpage.style.display ="block";

            }

else if (Brass > Guitar && Brass > Brass && Percussion > Keyboard && Brass > Woodwind) {
            var brasspage = document.getElementById("BrassPage");
            brasspage.style.display ="block";
            }

else if (Keyboard > Guitar && Keyboard > Keyboard && Percussion > Brass && Keyboard > Woodwind) {
            var keyboardpage = document.getElementById("KeyboardPage");
            keyboardpage.style.display ="block";
            }

else if (Woodwind > Guitar && Woodwind > Brass && Woodwind > Keyboard && Woodwind > Percussion) {
            var woodpage = document.getElementById("WoodwindPage");
            woodpage.style.display ="block";
                        }

else {
            var nonepage = document.getElementById ("NoPage");
            nonepage.style.display ="block";

            }
```

Comment: Hey I tried that but the else still shows up if any of the other variables are equal to each other??

Comment: the else will only show up if none of the above conditions equate to "true". You have to debug all the above conditions and make sure that atleast one of them results in true. If that does not happen, the else block will be executed.

Comment: So one of them was definitely true. It was 5. There were two others with 2 and both pages popped up?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple logic

```
var indices = ["GuitarPage","PercussionPage","BrassPage","KeyboardPage", "WoodwindPage"];
var allNumbers = [Guitar,Percussion,Brass,Keyboard,Woodwind];
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null,allNumbers);
var index =  allNumbers.indexOf(maxValue);
if ( maxValue > 0 )
{
   document.getElementById(indices[index]).style.display ="block";
}
else
{
  document.getElementById ("NoPage").style.display ="block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a function, if not already, and exit the function if a condition is true. The rest is skipped.

```
function compare() {
    if (Guitar > Percussion && Guitar > Brass && Guitar > Keyboard && Guitar > Woodwind) // Here I'm checking to see if Guitar is greater than the others
    {
        var guitarpage = document.getElementById("GuitarPage"); // If guitar is then get the Element ID "GuitarPage"
        guitarpage.style.display = "block"; // Then Display that page
        return;
    }

    if (Percussion > Guitar && Percussion > Brass && Percussion > Keyboard && Percussion > Woodwind) {
        var percussionpage = document.getElementById("PercussionPage");
        percussionpage.style.display = "block";
        return;
    }

    if (Brass > Guitar && Brass > Brass && Percussion > Keyboard && Brass > Woodwind) {
        var brasspage = document.getElementById("BrassPage");
        brasspage.style.display = "block";
        return;
    }

    if (Keyboard > Guitar && Keyboard > Keyboard && Percussion > Brass && Keyboard > Woodwind) {
        var keyboardpage = document.getElementById("KeyboardPage");
        keyboardpage.style.display = "block";
        return;
    }

    if (Woodwind > Guitar && Woodwind > Brass && Woodwind > Keyboard && Woodwind > Percussion) {
        var woodpage = document.getElementById("WoodwindPage");
        woodpage.style.display = "block";
        return;
    }            else {
        var nonepage = document.getElementById("NoPage");
        nonepage.style.display = "block";

    }
}

compare();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pageCond(Guitar, Percussion, Brass, Keyboard, Woodwind)
{
    if (Guitar > Percussion && Guitar > Brass && Guitar > Keyboard && Guitar > Woodwind) // Here I'm checking to see if Guitar is greater than the others
    { return "GuitarPage"; }

    if (Percussion > Guitar && Percussion > Brass && Percussion > Keyboard && Percussion > Woodwind)
    { return "PercussionPage"; }

    if (Brass > Guitar && Brass > Brass && Percussion > Keyboard && Brass > Woodwind)
    { return "BrassPage"; }

    if (Keyboard > Guitar && Keyboard > Keyboard && Percussion > Brass && Keyboard > Woodwind)
    { return "KeyboardPage"; }

    if (Woodwind > Guitar && Woodwind > Brass && Woodwind > Keyboard && Woodwind > Percussion)
    { return "WoodwindPage"; }

    return "NoPage";
}

var nodeID = pageCond(Guitar, Percussion, Brass, Keyboard, Woodwind);
document.getElementById(nodeID).style.display ="block";
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter: (updated)

```
var text = 'Guitar,Percussion,Brass,Keyboard,Woodwind';
var list = text.split(',').join('Page,').split(',');
var vars = eval('['+text+']');
var page = list[vars.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null,vars))];

document.getElementById(page || 'NoPage').style.display ="block";
```